# is it posible to pass pre-fetched data through ajaxSubmit() or ajaxForm() method in jquery

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to implement a form submission through ajax using ajaxSubmit(). I fetched values from the form and stored in a 'data' variable and trying to pass with the ajaxSubmit() function, is it possible or is there another method or plugins to do like this.

My html code is

```
<form action="pro.php" method="post" id="upform">
    <input type="text" name="name" id="name" />
    <input type="file" name="up" id="up" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="submit" />
</form>
```

jquery code is

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
    $("#upform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var name = $("#name").val();
        var file = $("#up").val();
        var data = "name=" + name + "&file=" + file;
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            dataType: 'json',
            url: 'pro.php',
            data: data,
            success: function (a) {
                alert(a.msg);
            },
            complete: function () {
                alert('complete process');

            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

looks like you are tyring to upload a file with ajax method... which is not possible ... howvere With XHR2, file upload through AJAX is supported using FormData object, but unfortunately it is not supported by all/old browsers.

either you need to use iframe to upload file through ajax or use available plugins...

[ajax upload](http://zurb.com/playground/ajax_upload) : simple jquery bases file uploader.. easy to use..

[uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com/) : jquery file upload plugins uses HTML5 and flash